# regex match() works in FF/Chrome but not IE 8

Tags: jquery, regex, internet-explorer-8

I have the following jQuery call, which returns a match in FF/Chrome, but returns null in IE 8.

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/4QQmR/1/) if you'd like to try it for yourself.

And here's the insoluble, unpliable, wayward code:

```
var m = $('#somediv').text().match(/\d+-(\d+)\sof\s(\d+)/);
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to Rob W. I've narrowed this a bit; the following works, so it's specifically the " of " or "\sof\s" that fails. Fork the fiddle and try a few for yourself :(

```
var m = $('#somediv').text().match(/\d+\D(\d+)\D+(\d+)/);
```

Comment: Works for me on IE 9, fails in IE 8 mode.

Comment: Ah, right, IE 8 -- updated description; thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on Rob W's answer, which picks up on the problem that `replace` doesn't replace globally by default, the other thing that's off here is the actual text you're searching for.  Rob W also points out that since you're getting the text with jQuery's `text()`, the `&nbsp;` entities have been decoded to actual, factual non-breaking space characters.

`&nbsp;` is a HTML entity, specifying it as an argument to `replace` isn't going to actually interpret it as a non-breaking space, it's just going to look for the actual text `&nbsp;` in the subject string.

Specifying the Unicode codepoint for the non-breaking space (00A0) in the search regex worked for me in IE 8 and IE 7 compatibility mode:

```
var m = t.replace(/\u00a0/g, ' ').match(/\d+-(\d+)\sof\s(\d+)/);
```

Things work correctly in IE 9 because it, like other browsers, includes non-breaking spaces in `\s`.  [Older versions of IE don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872046/internet-explorer-8-jscript-regular-expression-bug), and that's the only reason the replacement would be necessary.

Comment: looks promising! didn't work for me in IE 8; can you spot anything wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/pgtJr/2/

Comment: I spotted the issue; I switched to RegExp and forgot to double escape my spaces with \\s :)  Works great and thank you! How annoying that they don't translate to actual spaces!

Answer (score 2):

Your code would only replace the first occurence of `&nbsp;`. However, since you're getting the text using `.text()`, the `replace` function should not be needed.

```
var m = t.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ').match(/\d+-(\d+)\sof\s(\d+)/);
```

If your issue is not solved using the previous line, use `alert(t)` to check whether the input is as expected.

Comment: great catch on the match; also, I did not know that about text()!

Comment: Kato, I cannot test it in IE8, but try the following pattern: `\d+\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)/`

Comment: That does work in IE, unfortunately, I need a bit more specificity for this one; it's annoying but necessary

Answer (score 2):

Use this RegExp:

```
/\d+-(\d+)\xa0of+\xa0(\d+)/
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/KNbpN/

Sadly, it seems, IE8 doesn't recognize non-breaking spaces as a white-space (`\s`) match.