# .split() regex with capturing parentheses does not work in IE8

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-8

I have a regex which splits a string into an array at every space and keeps the space value in each occurrence as follows:

```
var str = "[This is a test]";
var foo = str.toLowerCase().split(/(\S+\s+)/).filter(function(n) {return n});
```

This returns the following on all modern browsers:

```
["[This ", "is ", "a ", "test]"];
```

But on IE8 all I get is `["test]"];`

It seems that IE8 doesn't read the `\S` regex character correctly. Does anyone know of a workaround for IE8 to reproduce the correct array?

Thanks

Comment: `\s` does not include non-breaking whitespace but it seems IE uses one. non-breaking whitespace is: `\xa0`. So you pattern becomes: `([^\s\xa0]+[\s\xa0]+)`

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935153/regex-match-works-in-ff-chrome-but-not-ie-8)
str.replace(/\u00a0/g, ' ')

Comment: Could anybody explain why this works in Chrome? :) `split` should remove the separator, should it not?

Comment: [I see now](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/string/split#Example:_Capturing_parentheses), `If separator contains capturing parentheses, matched results are returned in the array.` This seems to be the feature that does not work in IE8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not see why you're complicating things using `split()` and a callback. Just match instead of splitting !

`/\S+\s*/g`

- `\S+` : match any non-whitespace character one or more times.
- `\s*` : match any whitespace character zero or more times.
- `g`     : a modifier to match all.

Note: IE8 doesn't support `Array.filter()`.

<kbd>[**Online demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/x8Tyb/)</kbd>