# regex pattern.test() works in chrome but not in IE8

Tags: jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am checking regular expression in jquery part of my razor as below

```
function isValidarabicname(arabicname) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^[\u0600-\u06ff ]+$/);
    return pattern.test(arabicname);
};

$("#delBtn").on('click', function() {
    if (!isValidarabicname(arabicname)) {
        $("#errorDiv").show(500).html("Enter only arabic letters");
        $("#arabic_name").focus();
        error = 1;
    }
});
```

this validation is working fine in Chrome but it get failed in IE 8. Do i need to change anything to make it work in IE 8?

Comment: You're splitting a line of "string" code. Is that just a copy/paste mistake?

Comment: And possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935153/regex-match-works-in-ff-chrome-but-not-ie-8

Comment: can't understand the issue..i change it with .match() it is working fine in both browsers

Comment: Pretty sure it's related to that nbsp issue. If match works, just use that. Or drop support for IE8 lol!

Comment: @remus :) Even i don't like to support IE but some of my client is using it..any way match is working fine..