# Javascript and Internet explorer 8 error

Tags: javascript, html, regex, internet-explorer-8

I have the following lines of Javascript:

```
function SetTabIndex() {
    var test = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {

        var cssText = test[i].getAttribute('style'),
            tabindex = cssText.match(/tabindex\s*:\s*(\d+)/);

        if (tabindex) {
            test[i].setAttribute('tabindex', tabindex[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this locally, the script runs and does exactly what I want it to. But, when I put this on my target system (which only has IE8 and can't be updated) the code doesn't run.

I've checked my log and I get the following error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

When I click the link next to it, it takes me to the following line of code:

```
tabindex = cssText.match(/tabindex\s*:\s*(\d+)/);
```

I've tried taking out some of my regex code, but it still throws up an error. When I take that line away and throw in some console outputs, everything works fine.

Is there a particular reason as to why this doesn't work on IE8 even though I tested it locally on my more updated version of IE with it set to emulate IE8 just fine?

Comment: Is `cssText` the same type and value in all of the browers? Maybe IE8 returns something other than a string, which might not have the `match()` function available.

Comment: The above code is literally copied and pasted from my local machine to the other. How can I check to see what match returns?

Comment: `console.log` it out to inspect it, or add additional debug code. You can check the type with `typeof()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Internet explorer 8 JScript regular expression bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872046/internet-explorer-8-jscript-regular-expression-bug) the following answer was given:

> The issue here was that `"\s"` in javascript does not include a non breaking space in IE but includes a non breaking space in FF.

Comment: So how can I fix the issue? I just removed the \s but I still get the same error

Comment: @N0xus: Specify the character class directly, instead of using `\s`.

Comment: @nhahtdh how do I do that? I've never really used this stuff before

Comment: @N0xus: There are 2 ways: `[\s\u00a0]` (include no break space along with `\s`), **or** manually specify `\s` (which is quite long, if you may encounter EN SPACE, EM SPACE, or IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE).